# Clojure macros and quotes

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to 'get' clojure macros and write a tweaked version of the `are` macro in terms of the existing `are` macro. 
The tweak I want is to have signature `[argv expr args]` instead of `[argv expr & args]`
So I've tried

```
(defmacro are2 [argv expr args] `(clojure.test/are ~arg ~expr ~@args))
```

which kind of works, except it expects an unquoted list:

```
(are2 [input] (= 0 input) (1 2 3))
```

where I'd rather it expect a quoted list:

```
(are2 [input] (= 0 input) '(1 2 3))
```

But that results in:

```
Unable to resolve symbol: quote in this context.
```

If I try

```
(are2 [input] (= 0 input) (list 1 2 3))
```

instead then `list` itself gets processed as an test case.

What have I not understood / how can I get past the quote in my macro

Comment: Can show example of form after macroexpand? What do you want to get finally from `(are2 [input] (= 0 input) (1 2 3))`?

Comment: I want it to 'do whatever the clojure.test/are does but without the & in the sig ;-)
here's the code of clojure.test/are:
(defmacro are
  [argv expr & args]
  (if (or
       (and (empty? argv) (empty? args))
       ;; Catch wrong number of args
       (and (pos? (count argv))
            (pos? (count args))
            (zero? (mod (count args) (count argv)))))
    `(temp/do-template ~argv (is ~expr) ~@args)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "The number of args doesn't match are's argv."))))

Comment: But what I was trying to understand is, why is my attempt to re-use are failing

Comment: One more question. Why do you need to pass quote list to macro?

Comment: I don't 'need' to -- I want to understand why it doesn't work. Quoting is the usual way to pass a literal list around? Whereas passing around an unquoted list like (1 2 3) usually gets a Long cannot be cast to IFn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'(1 2 3)` is expanding into `(quote (1 2 3))` which has an extra `quote` symbol and one too many levels of list which you can see with macroexpand-1:

```
user> (macroexpand-1 '(are2 [input] (= 0 input) '(1 2 3)))
(clojure.test/are [input] (= 0 input) quote (1 2 3))
```

you can drop the quote from the list by wrapping it int first and rest

```
 user> (defmacro are2 [argv expr args] 
          `(clojure.test/are ~argv ~expr ~@(first (rest args))))
#'user/are2
user> (macroexpand-1 '(are2 [input] (= 0 input) '(1 2 3)))
(clojure.test/are [input] (= 0 input) 1 2 3)
```

which then runs as a test:

```
user> (are2 [input] (= 0 input) '(1 2 3)

FAIL in clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
expected: (= 0 1)
  actual: (not (= 0 1))

FAIL in clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
expected: (= 0 2)
  actual: (not (= 0 2))

FAIL in clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
expected: (= 0 3)
  actual: (not (= 0 3))
false
```

Comment: Would that be a usual way of addressing the problem? Or is my problem itself somewhat idiosyncratic?
In fact, is (first (rest )) not equivalent to (eval ...)?

Comment: as far as 'idiomatic' goes I think your macro is fine. If you want the syntax of using quoted lists that's what macros are for, so more power to ya'. (first(rest ..)) differs from (eval in that it wont fire up the compiler and it removes one level of nesting.